# "A network-related or instance-specific error occured" - but for which connectionstring?

Tags: c#, sqlclient

When trying to start debugging my application, I'm seeing a (very common) `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException` about "a network-related or instance-specific error" that apparently occurred.

I've understood that this means that there's a problem with my connection string, but I have quite a lot of different connectionstrings in my config files, that are used in different configurations etc, so I'm at a loss at knowing *which one* is giving me trouble.

Is there any way to find the connection string in use when this error is thrown?

Comment: You have so much reps and such vague question was not expected from you.. Put more info dear friend.. like what you tried or how is code structured or which ORM you are using or when this fails (any specific observations before you came to asking this question)

Comment: @HarshBaid: At least part of the reason why this question is quite vaguely formulated, is that I want to learn if there is an approach that is widely applicable. If there is a general approach, I can use it regardless of what ORM tool I'm currently using, how IoC is setup, etc... Just because the question was spawned from a specific situation, doesn't mean that situation is the only one I want to learn how to handle ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not necessarily a connection string problem but a failure to connect to a data source...e.g. a network connection issue

#### 1

The most straight-forward thing to do is to debug the application. When the exception is thrown you can easily traverse the call stack up until the call to `SqlConnection.Open` where you will be able to see the whole connection string. That's if you're using the `System.Data.SqlClient` provider's classes directly

#### 2

If you're using an ORM tool, it might be slightly more difficult and you will need to refer to the documentation of that specific tool in order to be able to output debug and/or tracing info

Wish I could be more specific, but the steps depends on how you have your data access logic set up because it varies a lot from one approach to another

### Example

I went in and opened a project that uses Fluent NHibernate and intentionally created a bug in the entity mappings below by misspelling the table name...

```
internal class RiskLevelDOMap : ClassMap<RiskLevelDO>
{
    internal RiskLevelDOMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);

        Map(x => x.MatrixId, "RiskMatrixId");
        Map(x => x.DisplayText).Length(256);
        Map(x => x.Description).Nullable().Length(2000);
        Map(x => x.BackgroundColor).Nullable().Length(64);
        Map(x => x.ForeColor).Nullable().Length(64);
        Map(x => x.DisplayInReports);
        Map(x => x.IsActive);

        Table("rm_RiskLevel1");
    }
}
```

ran the debugger and see the screenshot attached below...the connection string in plain text...

[image]

However, it's worth noting that I do have a pretty well-structure data access implementation where I'm spitting out a lot of debugging information

Comment: +1 for `the steps depends on how you have your data access logic set up because it varies a lot from one approach to another`

Comment: Thanks for the hints! I'm using NHibernate, and I wasn't able to find anything useful when debugging. However, I might just not have traversed the call stack high enough - I'll give it another try.

Comment: @TomasLycken, have a look the answer...you might get an idea

Answer (score 0):

In the exceptions dialog of Debug menu( Visual Studio), you can enable the debugger to stop on this error( System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException) specifically, then you could go up the call stack and see which string is being used...

Answer (score 0):

One approach may be logging `ClientConnectionId`s. These are available on both [`SqlConnection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.clientconnectionid(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`SqlException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.clientconnectionid(v=vs.110).aspx), assuming that the connection has been established.

- When connection is opened, log your connection string, along with the `ClientConnectionId` of your connection
- When you get an exception, log `ClientConnectionId`
- To find what connection string corresponds to DB that caused the exception, search through the log for the `ClientConnectionId` that you logged when establishing the connection.